# R Proportion Table Include All N Ways?

Tags: r

I know this is easily done in SAS, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this done in R. So, I'm trying to create a multi-way proportion table with all of the n-ways. What I mean by this is -

I know how to get something like this (this is a made up example):

```
prop_table<-as.data.frame(prop.table(table(df$Variable1,df$Variable2),1))   
view(prop_table)

    VariableA VariableB Freq  
    x1         y1        0.5   
    x2         y1        0.75  
    x1         y2        0.5 
    x2         y2        0.25
```

BUT I also want the one-way proportions...something like this:

```
VariableA VariableB Freq  
x1                   0.2  
x2                   0.8  
x1         y1        0.5  
x2         y1        0.75  
x1         y2        0.5  
x2         y2        0.25
```

Is there a way to do this without separately creating 1-way, 2-way...N-way tables and appending them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any built in function that will do all combinations for you, however it's not too many lines of code to write your own. Here's such a function

```
nprop.table <- function(x) {
  tbls <- Map(function(n) {do.call("table", list(bquote(x[,1:.(n), drop=FALSE]), 
      dnn=bquote(names(x)[1:.(n)])) )}, ncol(df):1)
  props <- Map(function(x) as.data.frame(prop.table(x,if(length(dim(x))>1){1} else {numeric(0)})), tbls)
  dplyr::bind_rows(props)
}
```

We can run it with

```
df <- expand.grid(Variable1=c("x1","x2"), Variable2=c("y1","y2"))[rep(1:4, c(10,60,10,20)),]
nprop.table(df)
#   Variable1 Variable2 Freq
# 1        x1        y1 0.50
# 2        x2        y1 0.75
# 3        x1        y2 0.50
# 4        x2        y2 0.25
# 5        x1      <NA> 0.20
# 6        x2      <NA> 0.80
```

It uses all the columns of the data.frame you pass in. So if you had three columns, it should still work

```
nsamp <- function(x, n) sample(x, n, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(Var1=nsamp(letters[1:3], 50), 
   Var2=nsamp(letters[4:6], 50), 
   Var3=nsamp(letters[7:8], 50))
nprop.table(df)
```

Comment: Your function works great. However, I'm playing around with the code a little because when I have more than 2 variables, the proportions are not quite what I want...it's showing the proportions with the total being each case of the first variable

Comment: That seems to be consistent what what you showed in your example. I'm unclear as to what you would want.

Comment: Yes it's consistent with my example because my example is 2-way but I realized it's a little different with more than 2 variables. For example, let's saty I also have Variable3 with possible values of z1 and z2. I would want the sum of the proportions for x1-y1-z1 and x1-y1-z2 to equal 1. With your function right now, it gives me the proportions with the total as cases with x1 regardless of what Variable2 is.

Comment: Ah! I just changed the "if(length(dim(x))>1){1}" part in the function to "if(length(dim(x))>1){c(1:(length(dim(x))-1))}". Works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets you most of the way there:

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr) # for the %>% pipe
mtcars %>%
  tabyl(cyl, am) %>%
  adorn_totals("row") %>%
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
  adorn_ns()

   cyl          0          1
     4 27.3%  (3) 72.7%  (8)
     6 57.1%  (4) 42.9%  (3)
     8 85.7% (12) 14.3%  (2)
 Total 59.4% (19) 40.6% (13)
```

To get it into your two-column form you can add a line calling `gather` from tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>%
  tabyl(cyl, am) %>%
  adorn_totals("row") %>%
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
  adorn_ns() %>%
  gather(am, proportion, -cyl)

    cyl am proportion
1     4  0 27.3%  (3)
2     6  0 57.1%  (4)
3     8  0 85.7% (12)
4 Total  0 59.4% (19)
5     4  1 72.7%  (8)
6     6  1 42.9%  (3)
7     8  1 14.3%  (2)
8 Total  1 40.6% (13)
```